# If specific select options hide checkbox else show checkbox

Tags: jquery, forms, hide, html-select

I'm trying to detect whether a particular group in my drop-down form field is selected so I can disable a check box but I can't quite work out the best way to select the whole group so if in the future that group expands it will still count all within the group. I've added the optgroup of tenancy for all the ones within the group

Here's the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/JLGtU/2/) so far.
Here's the code I have currently:

jQuery:

```
var thisVar = $('.QuickSearchProperties option:selected').val();

$('.QuickSearchProperties')on('change', function(){
    if(thisVar == 'ALLTEN', 'ALLTENUK', 'ALLTENOVERSEAS'){
       $('.ExcTen').addClass('hide');
    }else{
        $('.ExcTen').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <select name="QuickSearchProperties" class="QuickSearchProperties">
            <option value="a1" optGroup="Spain">Costa Del Sol</option>
            <option value="a2" optGroup="Spain">Almeria</option>
            <option value="a3" optGroup="Spain">Costa Blanca</option>
            <option value="a4" optGroup="Turkey">Turunc</option>
            <option value="a5" optGroup="Wales">Anglesey</option>
            <option value="a5" optGroup="Wales">Pembrokeshire</option>
            <option value="ALLTEN" optGroup="Tenancy">All Tenancy properties</option>
            <option value="ALLTENUK" optGroup="Tenancy">UK Tenancy properties</option>
            <option value="ALLTENOVERSEAS" optGroup="Tenancy">Overseas Tenancy properties</option>
    </select><br/><br/>

    <span class="ExcTen"><input type="checkbox" name="tenancy" value="1" />Exclude Tenancy </span>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.hide{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to hide the checkbox if any option of the `Tenancy` group is selected, you have to do like this:

```
$('.QuickSearchProperties').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).find("option:selected").attr("optGroup") == "Tenancy"){
        $('.ExcTen').addClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('.ExcTen').removeClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Check the [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLGtU/3/)

Comment: many thanks, exactly what I was after, knew it would be something involving .attr()

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.QuickSearchProperties').on('change', function(){
    if(['ALLTEN', 'ALLTENUK', 'ALLTENOVERSEAS'].indexOf($(this).val()) > -1){
        $('.ExcTen').addClass('hide');
    }else{
        $('.ExcTen').removeClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this isn't quite what I'm after, if you check out the jsfiddle I've updated(http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/JLGtU/2/) ive added a new option and it doesnt add the class to the checkbox, I'm thinking i'm going to need to detect any option thats selected and contains the optgroup tenancy